# Errors when trying to create a mysql database for rails spree project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, yaml

I am getting the following error when I am installing spree onto a new rails project utilising trying to use a mysql database. Installing spree I get the following error and I am not 100% how to solve it:

```
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-  3.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection': ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.5/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rd_searchlogic-3.0.1/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:61:in `ordering_condition_details'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rd_searchlogic-3.0.1/lib/search logic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:52:in `method_missing'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core/find_by_param.rb:105:in `<class:Base>'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core/find_by_param.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree-0.40.0/lib/spree.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree-0.40.0/lib/spree.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/Downloads/blind-love/blind-love/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    precompiling  assets
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

My database yaml file is as follows:-

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: blind_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


test:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: blind_test
pool: 5
username: root
password:
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: blind_production
pool: 5
username: root
password:
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue when using delayed_job, haven't found a workaround yet.

Edit: my issue was with what I believe is active record not being fully setup yet when I attempt to use it. When I pass the block I need to run to config.after_initialize in application.rb, the problem goes away.

Comment: The has been solved when I typed gem install spree what happened is spree e-commerce version 0.4 was being installed instead of version 1.0 , so in my gem file I specified version 1.0 and the issue was solved.